# How to detect where inline style is being added from?

Tags: javascript, css

I can't figure out where an inline style "style="position: absolute; left: 1247.69px; top: 42.4297px;" is coming from. Also, a class with the name drop-right is being added, as shown below.

To duplicate, go to https://newhavendisplay.com, add any product to the cart, and click the cart preview icon. The cart is displayed correctly on some pages, but on others, the cart is displayed to the right.

Examples:

https://newhavendisplay.com/blog/

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu is-open drop-right f-open-dropdown" id="cart-preview-dropdown" data-dropdown-content="" aria-hidden="false" style="position: absolute; left: 1248.328125px; top: 42.5px;">
```

https://newhavendisplay.com/quality/

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu is-open f-open-dropdown" id="cart-preview-dropdown" data-dropdown-content="" aria-hidden="false" style="position: absolute; left: 928.328125px; top: 98.5px;">
```

I tried using Chrome Dev tools > Break on → Attributes Modifications but I can't figure out the file or where this rule is being injected from as it differs from page to page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. External links are great for context, but they aren't substitutes for required question content.

Comment: Break on → Attributes Modifications shows me where the class and the style  was changed. It was in https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-ybeckn7x79/stencil/cc18d740-b015-013b-be66-0abcb1c4fb19/e/54e94ab0-c6a4-013b-286a-2ac3dfbdafb2/js/bundle.js btw

Comment: It could be in client script, but it could also be being added server-side. Your best bet would be to talk to the theme developer.